# Android OS totally kills application

Tags: android

I have a quite complicated app - there are few background services always running, sheduled alarms, static and dynamic broadcast receivers etc.
Also I have many log files, where all application activity is logged.
*Everything might work fine for a day, two days, even a week or more.*

But then everything, related to my app, stops working - alarms not firing, services not running and, what is the worst - static receivers stop firing `onReceive()`.

Behaviour is the same when I press "Force stop" in application settings.

**So my question is** - is there any possibility that Android system move my application in "Force stop" status? If so, why could that happen? Could not find any information about that so far.

PS. I've tried about 10 different devices with different OS version. It happenes everywhere.

Comment: I guess it's due to the new Android policy about limiting background services. Have you looked about that ?

Comment: Couldn't find any information about that. Can you provide some link?

Comment: I remember doing a research before as I was trying to make an unstoppable background service, I remember i tried to mark it as `STICKY` also tried to make another call to a broadcast receiver whenever `destroy` is been called.. all attempts failed.. so I noticed later that such thing could happen to known apps like Instagram, Whatsapp .. back then someone pointed that to me about Android policy of limiting background threats. But i can't recall the details sorry